# OpenGL doesn't draw with my own matrix

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I am trying to make a 2D game with opengl.I made the the class which draw meshes.And i made my own Matrix4f class.I have experience with 3D opengl.
When i pass my matrix4f to the shader it doesn't draw.But when i remove it from multiplying with the position the triangle appears on the screen.I tried my Matrix4f from my 3D Game Engine but it doesn't work as well.

Matrix4f class

```
package com.game.main.maths;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import com.game.main.util.Util;


public class Matrix4f {

    private float[][] m;

    public Matrix4f() {
        m = new float[4][4];

        initIdentity();
    }

    public Matrix4f initIdentity() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                if (x == y)
                    m[x][y] = 1.0f;
                else
                    m[x][y] = 0;

            }

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f translate(float x, float y, float z) {
        initIdentity();

        m[0][3] = x;
        m[1][3] = y;
        m[2][3] = z;

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f translate(Vector3f pos) {
        initIdentity();

        m[0][3] = pos.getX();
        m[1][3] = pos.getY();
        m[2][3] = pos.getZ();

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f rotate(float angle) {
        initIdentity();
        float rad = (float) Math.toRadians(angle);
        float cos = (float) Math.cos(rad);
        float sin = (float) Math.sin(rad);
        m[0][0] = cos;
        m[1][0] = sin;

        m[0][1] = -sin;
        m[1][1] = cos;

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f initOrthographic(float left, float right, float bottom,
            float top, float near, float far) {
        initIdentity();

        m[0][0] = 2.0f / (right - left);
        m[1][1] = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
        m[2][2] = 2.0f / (near - far);

        m[0][3] = (left + right) / (left - right);
        m[1][3] = (bottom + top) / (bottom - top);
        m[2][3] = (near + far) / (far - near);

        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f mul(Matrix4f matrix) {
        Matrix4f result = new Matrix4f();

        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                float sum = 0.0f;
                for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
                    sum += m[index][y] * matrix.get(x, index);

                result.set(x, y, sum);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public float[][] getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public float get(int x, int y) {
        return m[x][y];
    }

    public void setM(float[][] m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, float value) {
        m[x][y] = value;
    }

    public FloatBuffer toFloatBuffer() {
        return Util.createFlippedBufferBuffer(this);
    }
}
```

Shader class function

```
public void setUniform(String uniformName, Matrix4f matrix){
        int uniformLocation = getUniformLocation(uniformName);

        glUniformMatrix4(uniformLocation, false, matrix.toFloatBuffer());
    }
```

Util class

```
package com.game.main.util;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import com.game.main.graphics.Vertex;
import com.game.main.maths.Matrix4f;

public class Util {

    public static FloatBuffer createFlippedBuffer(float[] data){
        FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        buffer.put(data).flip();

        return buffer;
    }

    public static IntBuffer createFlippedBuffer(int[] data){
        IntBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();

        buffer.put(data).flip();

        return buffer;
    }

    public static IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int size){
        IntBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
        return buffer;
    }

    public static FloatBuffer createFloatBuffer(int size){
        FloatBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        return buffer;
    }

    public static FloatBuffer createFlippedBufferBuffer(Matrix4f matrix){
        FloatBuffer buffer = createFloatBuffer(4 * 4);

        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            buffer.put(matrix.get(x, y));

        buffer.flip();

        return buffer;
    }

    public static FloatBuffer createFlippedBuffer(Vertex[] vertecies){
        FloatBuffer buffer = createFloatBuffer(vertecies.length * Vertex.SIZE);

        for(int i = 0; i < vertecies.length; i++){
            buffer.put(vertecies[i].getPos().getX());
            buffer.put(vertecies[i].getPos().getY());
            buffer.put(vertecies[i].getPos().getZ());
            buffer.put(vertecies[i].getTexCoord().getX());
            buffer.put(vertecies[i].getTexCoord().getY());
        }

        buffer.flip();

        return buffer;
    }

}
```

Initializing the matrix uniform

```
Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f().initOrthographic(0, 800, 0, 600, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        Shader.Object.setUniform("mat", matrix);
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform mat4 mat;

void main(){

gl_Position = mat * vec4(pos, 1.0f);
}
```

Mesh class

```
package com.game.main.graphics;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

import com.game.main.util.Util;


public class Mesh {

    private int vbo, ibo, size;

    public Mesh(Vertex[] vertecies, int[] indices){
        vbo = glGenBuffers();
        ibo = glGenBuffers();
        size = indices.length;
        createMesh(vertecies, indices);
    }

    private void createMesh(Vertex[] vertecies, int[] indices){
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Util.createFlippedBuffer(vertecies), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Util.createFlippedBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void bind(){
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    }

    public void unbind(){
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void drawWithBinding()
    {
        bind();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        unbind();
    }

    public void draw(){
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }

    public void destroy(){
        glDeleteBuffers(ibo);
        glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    }
}
```

Vertex class

```
package com.game.main.graphics;

import com.game.main.maths.Vector2f;
import com.game.main.maths.Vector3f;

public class Vertex {

    private Vector3f pos = new Vector3f();
    private Vector2f texCoord = new Vector2f();
    public static final int SIZE = 5;

    public Vertex(Vector3f pos){
        this(pos, new Vector2f());
    }

    public Vertex(Vector3f pos, Vector2f texCoord){
        this.pos = pos;
        this.texCoord = texCoord;
    }

    public Vector3f getPos() {
        return pos;
    }

    public void setPos(Vector3f pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public Vector2f getTexCoord() {
        return texCoord;
    }

    public void setTexCoord(Vector2f texCoord) {
        this.texCoord = texCoord;
    }

}
```

transpose code

```
public Matrix4f transpose() {
        float m00 = get(0, 0);
        float m01 = get(1, 0);
        float m02 = get(2, 0);
        float m03 = get(3, 0);
        float m10 = get(0, 1);
        float m11 = get(1, 1);
        float m12 = get(2, 1);
        float m13 = get(3, 1);
        float m20 = get(0, 2);
        float m21 = get(1, 2);
        float m22 = get(2, 2);
        float m23 = get(3, 2);
        float m30 = get(0, 3);
        float m31 = get(1, 3);
        float m32 = get(2, 3);
        float m33 = get(3, 3);

        set(0, 0, m00);
        set(0, 1, m01);
        set(0, 2, m02);
        set(0, 3, m03);
        set(1, 0, m10);
        set(1, 1, m11);
        set(1, 2, m12);
        set(1, 3, m13);
        set(2, 0, m20);
        set(2, 1, m21);
        set(2, 2, m22);
        set(2, 3, m23);
        set(3, 0, m30);
        set(3, 1, m31);
        set(3, 2, m32);
        set(3, 3, m33);

        return this;
    }
```

Game class

```
package com.game.main;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import com.game.main.graphics.Mesh;
import com.game.main.graphics.Shader;
import com.game.main.graphics.Vertex;
import com.game.main.maths.Matrix4f;
import com.game.main.maths.Vector3f;

public class Game{

    private boolean running = false;
    private Mesh mesh;

    public Game(int width, int height){
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("2D Game");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f().initOrthographic(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        Shader.Object.setUniform("mat", matrix);

        Vertex[] vertecies = new Vertex[]{
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0,0)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0, 0.5f,0)),
                new Vertex(new Vector3f(0.5f, 0,0))

        };

        /*float[] vertecies = new float[]{
                -10f, -10f * 9.0f / 16.0f, 1,
                -10f, 10f * 9.0f / 16.0f,1,
                0, 10f * 9.0f / 1.0f,1,
                0, -10f * 9.0f / 6.0f,1
        };*/

        int[] ind = new int[]{
                0, 1, 2,
                2, 3, 0
        };

        mesh = new Mesh(vertecies, ind);
    }

private void init(){
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

public void start(){
if(running)
    return;

running = true;

gameLoop();
}

public void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;

    running = false;
}

private void gameLoop(){
    init();

    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0, updates = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();

        delta += (now - lastTime) / (1000000000.0 / 60.0);

        lastTime = now;

        while(delta >= 1){
            if(Display.isCloseRequested())
                stop();

            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            Display.setTitle("Frames: "+frames+" Updates: "+updates);
            frames = updates = 0;
        }
    }

    destroy();
}

private void update(){

}

private void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Shader.Object.bind();
    mesh.drawWithBinding();
    Shader.Object.unbind();
    Display.update();
}

private void destroy(){
    mesh.destroy();
    Display.destroy();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you possibly provide your code for drawing your objects?

Comment: I will do it but I don't think that is the problem.My shape is drawed when I don't multiply the matrix with the position.I will add the code when I come back to school

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in setting the matrix uniform. OpenGL is a state machine and doesn't remember uniform values. More importantly, **`glUniformMatrix4` must be called while the shader is in use**.

Currently, the matrix is set only at initialization (in the `Game` constructor), when it needs to be in `render()`.

```
Shader.Object.bind(); //glUseProgram(programHandle)
Shader.Object.setUniform(...) //glUniformMatrix4
mesh.drawWithBinding(); //glDrawElements
Shader.Object.unbind(); //glUseProgram(0), but not necessary unless you want fixed function rendering
```

With `mat` not being set it'd probably be a zero matrix that was stopping things from drawing.

---

In addition to the above, there are two other potential issues:

1. Take a look in the bottom left of your screen and see if that pixel is on. I suspect everything's working, [just really small](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036896/1888983). If the following works:

   ```
   gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0f);
   ```

   which is essentially a multiply by the identity matrix and nearly `ortho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)` (except the ortho call gives `mat[2][2]=-1`), then I'm guessing your mesh is around the size of a unit cube.

   Introducing `mat` = `initOrthographic(0, 800, 0, 600, -1.0f, 1.0f)` looks like it's set up for a scene where vertices are given in pixels. The origin will be bottom left and if the mesh fits in a unit cube will draw to at most one pixel.
2. See @Jerem's answer about row/column major matrices.

Comment: Well i did that it still didn't work.See my code on the post.

Comment: I transpose the matrix before seting the uniform.Tried everything still nothing.I wonder why when i do 3D my matrix is working here not .

Comment: @user3723184 Try passing in the identity matrix. When you get that working, throw in a call to `initOrthographic(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)`. Should be the same except negate `z`. I also think Jerem is correct about the row major matrices. Try some different values and transpose it right before passing as a uniform.

Comment: @user3723184 in regard to calling `glUniformMatrix4` while the shader is in use/active. Currently it looks like you only call it once when `Game` is initialized.

Comment: ohh.Yeah i ddin;t saw that thanks.But still it isnt working can u check if my transpose method is right or not.

Comment: @user3723184 your point about it working without `mat` in the shader but not with gives it away. The immediate problem must be that `mat` is not being set correctly. So try setting to the identity matrix and get that working first. Perhaps there is an issue with `getUniformLocation`?

Comment: Well i checked the uniormLocation it returns 0.So it is valid.IDK

Comment: Oh. Throw some `glGetError` calls around and see if that turns up anything useful.

Comment: The glGetError show 1282.The string shows Invalid Operation

Comment: @user3723184 Great. Now you'll have to narrow down which line that came from (by calling from various locations) and if there is more than one error. Hopefully it's related to your problem and leads to the answer.

Comment: @user3723184 I'm intrigued to know what the problem was in the end. I assume with the accept that you've found it.

Comment: Well i went to make a 3D game Engine.And it worked the code was the same thing just more compact.Then i tried 2D again and i got invalid operation again.IDK if it is that on my java project i put 2D :D:DD:D:D:D: or i am just doing something wrong.I copy paste the same code from 3d engine to 2d Game Opengl project.Invalid operation.I am just shocked

Comment: @user3723184 glad to hear you found it in the end!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your matrix is row major. You need to transpose it before sending it to the shader.

Note that there is a boolean parameter called transpose in glUniformMatrix4f but you can't use it in opengl es - the doc says it has to be false - you have to transpose it yourself.

Comment: well i tried to transpose it it didn;t work as well.

Comment: What did it do? Can you post what you changed in the code?

Comment: Well i saw how lwjgl transpose it;s matrix and i tried that.I edited my post see the code there.